# Como pegar parte de uma String até um caractere especificado?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de um método JavaScript que pegasse parte de uma String até determinado ponto (caracter) dela. No caso eu especificaria um caractere e só seria pego parte da String até o caracter que eu especifiquei.

- Eu não gostaria de utilizar os métodos `substring`, `indexOf` ou o `split`. Pois eles exigem que eu faça isso em mais de uma linha de código (usando array ou índices) e, no meu problema específico, isso precisa ser feito em uma única linha.

**Exemplo do que eu precisaria:**

```js
let frase = "99 troços";

//Eu precisaria disso (que está abaixo) só que sem utilizar outras linhas de código antes da variável armazenarValor.
let armazenarValor = "99"; //Ignoraria o espaço e o 'troços'.


//Eu precisaria que ficasse algo assim
let armazenarValor = pegarAteEspaco(frase, " ");
//Imaginemos que pegarAteEspaco() fosse um método JavaScript que pegasse uma String até determinado caracter.
//Eu só gostaria de pegar o "99" e ignorar o resto.
```

- Eu não poderia fazer uma função para isso também.
- Em PHP tem métodos que fazem isso. Mas eu gostaria de fazer em JS.
- Vi algumas coisas aqui no Stack Overflow, mas a maioria é usando `substring`, `split` ou `indexOf`.
- Talvez não exista algo nativo do JS feito exatamente pra isso.

Comment: Sem essas funções você precisa de um loop, o que complica resolver numa linha (requisito mais esquisito!) Usando substring + indexOf dá pra fazer em uma linha...

Comment: Obrigado, bfavareto.  A questão de uma expressão regular, citada na resposta do Luiz Felipe, me pareceu bem interessante. Mas acho que também não seria em uma única linha. Na verdade acho que não exista algo nativo do JavaScript que faça isso.

Comment: Mas por que não simplesmente `let trecho = frase.substring(0, frase.indexOf(' '))`?

Comment: Daqui a pouco vou testar direitinho sua resposta, Luiz Felipe. Dando certo, eu dou o vote e aceito ela ;D

Comment: Complementando o @bfavaretto, também dá pra fazer `let valor = frase.split(' ')[0]`. Isso é só uma linha...

Comment: talvez também dê certo, @bfavaretto. Vou testar daqui a pouco e retorno pra vocês o resultado.

Comment: Ah, já entendi... Você está rodando esse código num desses sites de cursos/desafios, né? Só eles colocam esses requisitos absurdos, como resolver em uma linha...

Comment: Ao escrever um código em "uma linha", você estará muitas vezes abrindo mão da legibilidade do código por um fator que raramente "importa" no longo-prazo. A legibilidade é, geralmente, muito mais importante que o número de linhas. Acho que vale a pena rever a necessidade de fazer em "uma linha"... :)

Comment: Pior que não, @bfavaretto. É uma necessidade que pintou aqui no trabalho. Eu estou utilizando o Chart Js e pintou uma treta aqui que tive que fazer isso para resolver o problema.

Comment: @LuizFelipe, eu não costumo fazer isso. Foi a necessidade mesmo. Na verdade é a primeira vez que faço isso.

Comment: Pior que agora tiveram várias respostas que talvez resolvam. Vou dar preferência a quem respondeu primeiro a também as que eu consiga realmente entender. Eu não sei utilizar expressão regular, porém a resposta do @LuizFelipe, foi a primeira.

Comment: Vc deve aceitar a que melhor resolveu o problema para vc, independente da ordem :-)

Comment: Então, a resposta do @hkotsubo me atendeu legal, tentei até acrescentar alguns números depois do espaço mas realmente só saiu o 99. Mas eu achei essa questão do parseInt() meio sinistra para tal situação. Já a resposta do Luiz Felipe também me atendeu de forma ótima. Porém eu entendo nada de expressão regular (E utilizar algo no código que você não entende é meio chato) e não sei se poderia abrir alguma brecha para erros no meu caso. Os dois me ajudaram bastante. Estou na dúvida de qual resposta aceitar. Qualquer uma das escolhas, seria injusto com o outro.

Comment: Fica a seu critério escolher qualquer uma delas. No seu caso, é interessante ler esta discussão: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1540/112052 - particularmente, eu não acho que seria "injusto" comigo dado que a outra resposta do Felipe também ficou boa (e esse uso do `parseInt` eu tb não gosto, sei lá, prefiro não depender dessas "mágicas"). Enfim, vc decide :-)

Comment: Dilema, cara. Acho que o parseInt não seja a forma correta pra essa minha questão, porém funcionou. A expressão regular funcionou, porém eu entendi nada e não sei se outros usuários, meio leigos como eu, não entenderiam também. Já viu aquele meme em que o cara fica na dúvida entre dois botões para apertar ? É como estou agora. Rs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar uma expressão regular para fazer isso:

```js
const string = '99 troços';

const [, match] = string.match(/(\S+) /) || [];

console.log(match);
```

Na expressão regular acima, criamos um grupo de captura para obter o valor desejado. Dentro desse grupo, usamos `\S+` para dar *match* em **um ou mais** caracteres que não sejam espaço em branco (como espaços, quebras de linha, tabs, etc). Em seguida, esperamos que sempre após esse grupo de captura, exista um espaço.

Como o [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) pode retornar `null` caso a expressão regular não encontre ocorrências, utilizei um *fallback* no final, para que um *array* sempre seja retornado, e sempre sejamos capazes de fazer a desestruturação.

---

Você também pode escrever o código em uma única linha:

```js
const [, match] = '99 troços'.match(/(\S+) /) || [];
console.log(match);

// Ou se você realmente quiser em uma linha mesmo:
console.log(('99 troços'.match(/(\S+) /) || [])[1]);
```

Mas eu realmente não sei um motivo para que você queira fazer isso, já que deixa o código bem ilegível, pelo menos usando essa forma. Conforme colocado nos comentários ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433174/como-pegar-uma-string-at%c3%a9-um-caracter-especificado#comment838341_433174), pelo @bfavaretto; e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433174/como-pegar-uma-string-at%c3%a9-um-caracter-especificado#comment838343_433174), pelo @hkotsubo), há outras formas mais "elegantes" de se fazer isso em uma única linha.

Comment: Só lembrando que o `\S` ignora vários outros caracteres além do espaço, como o TAB e quebras de linha (a lista completa está [na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes)). Para o caso da pergunta não faz diferença porque a string não tem esses outros caracteres, mas de qq forma fica o registro. Se quiser ignorar **somente** espaços, pode usar `[^ ]` (repare que há um espaço entre o `^` e o `]`

Answer (score 6):

Bom, existe uma alternativa - na minha opinião, meio "feia" - e que "serve" especificamente para o caso da pergunta (que possui números no começo). Deixo aqui só como curiosidade:

```js
let frase = "99 troços";
let valor = parseInt(frase);
console.log(valor); // 99
```

Isso só "funciona" porque [segundo a documentação de `parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> *If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point.*

Em tradução livre:

> Se `parseInt` encontra um caractere que não é um numeral na base especificada, ele ignora esse e todos os caracteres seguintes e retorna o inteiro que foi lido até aquele ponto.

Ou seja, ele lê o `99` e quando encontra o espaço, para de ler. No final o resultado é 99.

---

Claro que se a situação for outra (string não começa com números, etc), aí é melhor usar as soluções das outras respostas. Se bem que para esses casos ainda prefiro usar `substring`, `split` e `indexOf`.

Comment: Isso é covardia, né não ?

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. Eu não diria covardia, só estou aproveitando a forma como a função foi implementada :-) Se bem que em código de produção eu usaria `substring` ou `split` para deixar mais claro o que está sendo feito...

Comment: Escolhi a outra, @hkotsubo, mas a sua resposta também seria útil pra mim. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Não entendi esse requisito de não utilizar o método [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) é um método nativo da linguagem divide um objeto String em um array de strings ao separar a string em substrings.

Nesse caso ao invés de procurar por separações basta limitar a ação do método a primeira ocorrência do separador por meio do parâmetro `limite`.

```js
let texto = "99 troços a 99 centavos ";

console.log(pegarAteEspaco(texto, " "));

function pegarAteEspaco(frase, separador) {
  return frase.split(separador, 1)[0]
}
```

Mesmo código em uma linha:

```
console.log("99 troços a 99 centavos ".split(" ", 1)[0])
```

Comment: Sim, @Augusto Vasques. Sua função executou legal. Mas como eu havia mencionado na descrição da pergunta, eu preciso de algo que só gastasse uma linha de código e não utilizasse função. Mas mesmo assim eu agradeço o seu tempo disponibilizado para tentar ajudar no meu problema.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. Se a questão é uma linha basta só usar isso `console.log("99 troços a 99 centavos ".split(" ", 1)[0])`

Comment: É, Augusto. Sua situação também foi útil.

Comment: Escolhi a outra resposta, pelo cara ter respondido primeiro e também porque eu tinha mencionado, na descrição da pergunta, que não deveria ser com split. Mas as sua resposta também seria útil pra mim. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar slice combinado com indexOf:

```
const string = 'example@example.com';

const newString = string.slice(0, string.indexOf('@'));

console.log(newString);
// saída example
```

Comment: A tradução já melhorou bastante a postagem, seria interessante complementar explicando o que o `slice` e o `indexOf fazem`, potencializando a resposta como uma boa referência para futuros visitantes.

Comment: Isso também funcionaria pra mim.