# Valor retornado está sendo o mesmo do valor digitado

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com problema ao exibir o resultado em converter decimal para binário.

Quando faço dessa maneira definindo o 2020 na variável decimal, retorna o valor correto que é **11111100100**

```
var decimal = 2020;
var binario = decimal.toString(2);
alert(binario);
//retorna 11111100100
```

Porém, quando passo a utilizar input do HTML, o resultado não é o esperado. Ele sempre retorna o mesmo valor que digito no input.

```
<input type="text" id="decimal-input">
<input type="button" value="CONVERTER" onclick="convertDec()">

function convertDec() {
   var decimal = document.getElementById('decimal-input').value;
   var binario = decimal.toString(2);
   alert(binario);
   //retorna sempre o mesmo valor que foi digitado no input do ID decimal-input, e não retorna no formato binário
}
```

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O [atributo `value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) de um `input type="text"` é uma string, então primeiro você deve convertê-lo para número.

Como você quer um número inteiro, use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```js
function convertDec() {
    var decimal = parseInt(document.getElementById('decimal-input').value);
    if (isNaN(decimal)) {
        alert("não foi digitado um número");
    } else {
        var binario = decimal.toString(2);
        alert(binario);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="decimal-input">
<input type="button" value="CONVERTER" onclick="convertDec()">
```

Se não for digitado um número inteiro válido, `parseInt` retorna [`NaN` (not-a-number)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), que pode ser verificado com [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Lembrando ainda que existe [esse *corner case*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/433182/112052).

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou bastante !!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa converter o valor que recebeu no input para Number. Isso pode ser feito usando `parseInt()` ou `Number()`. Ficaria assim:

```js
var decimal = parseInt(document.getElementById('decimal-input').value);
```

O seu código estava mostrando o mesmo valor porque o tipo da variável `decimal` é String. Quando você chama a função toString em uma String, ela retorna o mesmo valor.

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou bastante !!